# Custom Control - How to get compositeData in onClientLoad

Tags: xpages, custom-controls

After a timeout I logout the user and redirect to Login as described here:

[NotesSpeak](http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/06/force-your-expired-xpage-to-return-to.html)

A part of this code is executed in `onCliendLoad()`.

```js
    var thisUrl = window.location.pathname;
    var finalPath = thisUrl + "?Logout&redirectto=" + thisUrl + "?opendatabase&login";
    setAutoRefresh(15000, finalPath);
```

Now I want to use it on several XPages and add a custom control. With a custom property (needsLogout) I want to decide if the timeout should executed or not.

I created a custom control and a custom property called needsLogout. On SSJS I get this property using compositeData.needsLogout.

But I need this property in the onClientLoad. But this is CSJS and compositeData is not defined.

Is it possible to get the property in CSJS?

Sebastian

Comment: What computational problem are you trying to solve? Can you provide your sample code, including where you want to utilize the property. Your compute problem might have a very different solution than your property approach

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added more information and some code in my question. Maybe it could help to understand what I want to do.

Comment: let your custom control compute client side js and use ${} JSF syntax to insert your property value

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like charm. I think I need some basics. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code in `onClientLoad()` looks like this.

```
if (!${compositeData.needsLogout}) {return false} 
else {
var thisUrl = window.location.pathname;
var finalPath = thisUrl + "?Logout&redirectto=" + thisUrl + "?opendatabase&login";
setAutoRefresh(15000, finalPath);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).